# Find and group values that match in a specific column, based on a predicate

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group the value in column `m` for all rows that have the same first value in the list in column `z`.

Sample Input:

```
m     p   z
x001  Foo [z42, z56, z31]
x321  Bar [z589, z78, z42]
x5432 Paz [z67]
x003  Foo [z589, z78, z32, z31]
x5478 Bah [z987, z345, z52]
x098  Fin [z42, z31]
x783  Lon [z42, z210, z458, z192]
```

Desired Output:

```
[x001, x098, x783]
[x321, x003]
```

Note that values in column `m` are unique, while values in other columns may repeat and/or match exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to group by the first ([0]th) element of the "z" column, so we do that:

```py
In [171]: df.groupby(df.z.str[0])["m"].agg(list)
Out[171]:
z
z42     [x001, x098, x783]
z589          [x321, x003]
z67                [x5432]
z987               [x5478]
Name: m, dtype: object
```

There exist only 1 record-having first values, so we can filter them out:

```py
In [172]: res = _

In [173]: res[res.str.len() > 1]
Out[173]:
z
z42     [x001, x098, x783]
z589          [x321, x003]
Name: m, dtype: object
```

where `res` is the result of the first operation.

Even though the `.str` accessor by name seems to be for string operations, due to duck typing, we can use them (e.g., indexing or length) on lists as well, as seen above.